# javascript use string with \u (Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence)

Tags: javascript

how to display this string without error

```
console.log("Rue yp`tHe_tQRc@DIBInBgE\u@HS");
```

error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence

Comment: Escape the backslash?

Comment: `console.log("Rue yptHe_tQRc@DIBInBgE\\u@HS");`

Which means escape the backslash

Comment: I can not change
it is a data from another source
I search for a solution without changing the value of string

Comment: If the data contains a literal backslash, you don’t need to do anything. If the data contains an invalid Unicode escape sequence, you need to fix whatever produced the data. If that string is actually a variable, then the code you’ve shown doesn’t throw the error. Anything else is impossible; it’s this simple.

Comment: Where is the string coming from?  Ajax?  Passed in by php or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is - you can't - not as a javascript variable at this point in your code.  You would have to put that string into an HTML element and then get the innerText of that element, or change/escape the string before it gets to your javascript.